# Infinite loop in Java program stops printing out information

Tags: java, infinite-loop, system.out

My problem is kind of strange. I have made a program in Java which fetches some information from a website, writes it to a file and prints it out in the console. It works fine when I start it but after a several passes it stops printing the information out while it continues to write them to the file. I have observed this behavior and figured out that it occurs totally randomly.
It is pretty large and has 15 classes so I don't think it's useful to completely paste it here but I'll make a pattern:

```
while(true) {
    InfoStoringClass isc = new InfoStoringClass(getInformation());
    printToFile(isc);
    System.out.println(isc.toString());
}
```

Comment: It's hard to say with this amount of detail. Could `printToFile()` be modifying the `isc` object?

Comment: I would debug the program step by step, and monitor `isc` closely.

Comment: Could writing to the file or retrieving the info from the website (since it's synchronous) be hanging, and then the loop can't continue 'til the request is complete?

Comment: Can you add more System.out.println debug messages (say before getInformation and before printToFile) just to make sure isc.toString doesn't return empty string?

Comment: Are you sure that there's nothing else in the program that might close `System.out` ?